# Change UI without lose Bluetooth connection

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, bluetooth

I have 2 fragments which extends a Bluetooth fragment (connect, send, receive). The difference between the fragments is, that one have buttons and the other have an editText.

The Problem is, that when I change between them, the BT connection get lost, because I extend again the BT Fragment. How can I access my BT fragment from multiple other fragments? Can I acces from the button fragment over the FragmentActivity to the BT fragment? Or is an Interface the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to separate BT layer from presentation layer. Use a `Service` to maintain BT connection, fetch data and forward it to the UI. Use fragments to subscribe to notifications coming from your service, e.g. via `LocalBroadcastManager` and display the data.